# Ideas to prevent adult images being uploaded to photo site

Tags: php, javascript, image, flash, photos

I run a small photo site. It has recently come to my attention that a number of the images being uploaded are adult in nature. I need a good simple way to prevent the uploading of adult images if possible. Any ideas would be helpful, thanks.

Also, the site is running using pretty much PHP, JavaScript, and flash.
http://superlame.com

Comment: Good luck with finding a "good simple way" to do this.  A Google search for ["how to detect adult images"](https://www.google.com/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=how+to+detect+adult+images) shows you a lot of the research going on in different ways to do this.

Comment: Previously, on a project having a simple "flag inappropriate" link helped us a lot. If there is a flag weight > 5, we send it for review. And a flag weight > 10 was automated blocked from public views.

Comment: So I've just checked your website, there doesn't seem to be a way to search your data or accidentally stumble upon those porn images. One should actually have the link to the file with random-looking filename. Plus, the images seem to be deleted in 24 hours.
And if you're concerned with your host's ToS, you can use encryption to store the files.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you take a look at [nude.js](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/nudejs/). Perhaps that's all you need. It seems like the perfect solution to your problem.

Comment: Really wanted this to work. Thanks for the heads up, maybe it'll improve with time.

So, I tried this on a decent amount of images, the majority of which are clean and absolutely none of the adult images were tagged, however a handful of the known clean images were filtered out.

Comment: That's counter productive. =)

Answer (score 2):

[Here's a PHP port](https://github.com/azwan082/php-nudity-filter) of [nude.js](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/nudejs/), I've just tried it and , to some extent, it seems to be working.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the PHP one as well. Unfortunately it didn't quite work out as I'd have liked. Guess I'll have to stick to observe and ban.

Answer (score 1):

there are a few options but you never can fully preven it

1. Buy a script that recognize adult images.
2. Make a adult section.
3. Create a button to report adult images.
4. Check each incoming photo by yourself.

The first option is expensive, the second gives you more visitors and the last gives you more spammers,

Kind regards,